# How to convert linux gradle command into windows

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I am trying to build a mobile sdk for liferay services using gradle. I have created directory root/modules/serviceName using gradlew createTask. Now Liferay documentation says go to root/modules/serviceName and execute **../../gradlew generate**. Can anyone please help to convert this command into windows? Thanks!

Comment: `..\..\gradlew generate` You can also do `..\..\gradlew.bat ganerate` which is the same

Comment: @Alex I tried as you mentioned but it gives following result  -- '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Make sure you are don't have a space between `..` and the backslash

Comment: Thanks @Alex for your response